# save objects from views to another table drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am trying to save data in this table but i'm getting two field only and all the other i want to add manually

models.py:

```
class ProviderStatus(UUIDBase):
      provider_id = models.ForeignKey(Provider, to_field="uid", db_column='provider_id', verbose_name=_("Provider id"),on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
      created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field="uid", db_column='created_by', verbose_name=_("created by"),on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
      remark = models.TextField(_("Remark"), blank=True, null=True)
      effective_date_from = models.DateField(_("Effective Date From"),auto_now_add=False,auto_now=False, null=True)
      effective_date_to = models.DateField(_("Effective Date To"), null=True)
      provider_status = models.ForeignKey(ProviderStatusChoice, to_field="key", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Status"), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ProviderStatusSerilaizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model = ProviderStatus
            fields= ('uid','provider_id','created_by','remark','effective_date_from','effective_date_to','provider_status')
```

views.py:

i have other view and inside that i'm getting output parent_success_obj from that i'm getting its uid and also getting status field and i want to save these fields in this table

```
    provider_id =  parent_success_obj.uid  
    provider_status = status
```

and other fields i'm taking null or date.now()
how should i proceed in views.py:

```
        if 'parent_success_obj.uid':            
            serializer_obj = ProviderStatusSerilaizer(data=data)
            if serializer_obj.is_valid():
                serializer_obj.save()
            else:
                return CustomeResponse(request=request, comment=FIELDS_NOT_VALID, data=json.dumps(serializer_obj.errors, cls=UUIDEncoder), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, validate_errors=1)
```

edits:

```
        provider_id = parent_success_obj.uid
        provider_status = parent_success_obj.provider_status

        new_data = {"provider_id":provider_id,
                    "remark":"demo remark",
                    "provider_status":provider_status,
                    "created_by": "91bd783f-070a-49ca-a87e-26a4fa157c62",
                    "effective_date_from": "2020-03-03",
                    "effective_date_to": "2020-03-03",

        }

        serializer_obj = ProviderStatusSerilaizer(data=new_data)
        if serializer_obj.is_valid():
            serializer_obj.save()
```

this is working but how can i edit this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send this data some how to the view where you are using this `ProviderStatusSerilaizer`. There are many ways to do that. One of them is to use [**`session`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/). You can store the these date in session like this:

```
request.session['provider_id'] = parent_success_obj.uid
request.session['provider_status'] = status
```

Now in your provider serializer, you can send the [**request object through context**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context):

```
if request.session.get('provider_id'):
    serializer_obj = ProviderStatusSerilaizer(data=data,context={'request':request})
    if serializer_obj.is_valid():
        serializer_obj.save()
```

And override the `create` method of `ProviderStatusSerilaizer` to utilize the request object:

```
class ProviderStatusSerilaizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model = ProviderStatus
            fields= ('uid','created_by','remark','effective_date_from','effective_date_to',)  # I am removing provider_id and provider_status as I will be injecting this data separately

      def create(self, validated_data):
          request = self.context['request'] 
          provider_id = request.session['provider_id']
          status = request.session['provider_status']
          # Now delete data from sesssion
          del request.session['provider_status']
          del request.session['provider_id']
          validated_data['provider_status'] = status
          validated_data['provider_id'] = provider_id
          return super().create(validated_data)
```

**FYI**, please do not name ForeignKey fields with suffix id(ie `<field_name>_id`), because underneath, django creates the field with `id` suffix. So if you name your FK field `abc`, django will create a field with `abc_id` automatically.

### Update

If you are getting `provider_id` and `status` in same view, then you can pass that as context as well.

```
# View
if parent_success_obj.uid:            
    serializer_obj = ProviderStatusSerilaizer(
        data = data,
        context = {
            'provider_id': parent_success_obj.uid,
            'provider_status': status
        }
    )

# Serializer

class ProviderStatusSerilaizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProviderStatus
        fields= ('uid','created_by','remark','effective_date_from','effective_date_to',)  # I am removing provider_id and provider_status as I will be injecting this data separately

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.update(self.context) # updating validated data dictionary with context dictionary
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Comment: actually i'm getting provider_id and provider_status in that view